# Javascript not working on Iphone4

Tags: javascript, html, iphone

I got simple JavaScript code on external file. It works on desktop, but in iPhone4 and in galaxy4  it's not working

```
document.write("Hello");
```

Any tip where to start looking at?

Comment: Start by looking into why `document.write` is a bad idea to insert content dynamically, and what the current methods to do this are.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method:

```
var objectContainer = createElement("div");
objectContainer.innerHTML = "Hello";
var messDiv = document.getElementById("MessageDiv");
messDiv.appendChild(objectContainer);
```

Comment: for this I get this error on my desktop "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null"

Comment: try using "document.getElementById('MessageDiv')" insted. and create the div 'MessageDiv' in your html, the div where u want to show your message. i will edit my answer

Comment: do you added a div with this id: "MessageDiv" ?

Comment: do you use jquery library in your project?

Comment: and also in 3.2.1

Comment: so try $("#messDiv").html("Hello") instead